# predictive attributes in WEKA

Tags: data-mining, weka

I am trying to select the best attributes for my training data set which contains numeric values/attributes. which attribute evaluator/method would yield the best results for about 10 or so attributes? Training dataset is about 1400 lines of population statistics data.

Comment: I forgot to add that there are over 100 attributes, and over 1000 instances.